# Создать свою функцию

Tags: sql, postgresql

работаю в PgAdmin. Хочу создать свою функцию. Нужно перевести цену в другую валюту. На вход она будет принимать курс и код недвижимости. По коду я могу найти текущую цену, но как мне с этим числом производить дальнейшие вычисления ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION course(integer, integer) RETURNS bigint
    AS 'SELECT "price" FROM "Object_estate" WHERE "Object_estate"."code_object"=$2'
    LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT * FROM course(2, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался, использовал доп. функцию для получения результата

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.findPrice(integer) RETURNS bigint
    AS 'SELECT "price" FROM "Object_estate" WHERE "Object_estate"."code_object"=$1'

    LANGUAGE sql;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION course1(bigint, integer) RETURNS bigint
    AS 'select $1 * $2;'

    LANGUAGE SQL;


SELECT * FROM course1(findPrice(2), 2);
```